# I'm getting '405 method not found' error for the above code and error during log rotation

Tags: node.js, web, logging, error-handling, system

```js
 try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/rotateLogs', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({}),
```

Here I am getting an error near fetch which says method not allowed. I have tried to check firewalls and also client-side JS everything seems fine

```bash
POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/rotateLogs net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your client code is making a POST request, however HTTP status 405 usually means that the server side code is expecting a different verb such as GET, PUT or DELETE. Please edit your question to include the server side code which is listening at /api/rotateLogs, One important thing to note is the fact that you have a HTTP status code means your client is getting a response from the server, whereas a firewall problem would normally cause the request to be blocked completely, meaning that the client wouldn't receive a response at all.